# Function in React ES6 class doesn't change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      generations: 0,
      rows: 30,
      cols: 30,
      isGoing: false,
      speed: 500,
      gameField: []
    }

    this.generateGameField()
  }

  generateGameField() {
    var result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
      result[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.state.cols; j++) {
        result[i][j] = Math.round(Math.random());
      }
    }
    console.log(result)
    this.setState({ gameField: result })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state)}>Click me</button>
    )
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.body
)
```

Please help me. Function generateGameField supposed to create new array and fill it with 0 or 1. The function actually create array, but doesn't change state. Within the function I have access to the state, so I just don't know what went wrong

Comment: If you're going to set state in the constructor, why not just put it in as initial state? Return `result` from `generateGameField` and in `this.state = { ... }` do `gameField: this.generateGameField()`.

Comment: Thank you. I knew this, but I want to know why my code doesn't do what it supposed to do. I mean why my function has access to the state but can't change it?

Comment: Yes, setState is asynchronous. But I added a button which supposed to print my state after click on it. And state won't change at all. I can click button after 5, 10, 15 sec and state will remain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to initialize the component. If that's what you want to achieve then you should use the react life cycle method; [componentWillMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount).

So to fix the bug, rename `generateGameField` function to `componentWillMount` and reorganize the code as below:

```
  class Main extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
     }

     componentWillMount() {
       let result = [];
       const rows = 30;
       const cols = 30;
       for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           result[i] = [];
           for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              result[i][j] = Math.round(Math.random());
           }
       }
       console.log(result)
       this.setState({
         generations: 0,
         rows: 30,
         cols: 30,
         isGoing: false,
         speed: 500,
         gameField: result
       })

     }

     render() {
        return (
        <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state)}>Click me</button>
        )
     }

 }

 ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.body)
```

This what I found in the react official documentation:

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
>
> This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead.

Abiding by that the above code could be modified to:

```
  class Main extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       let result = [];
       const rows = 30;
       const cols = 30;
       for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           result[i] = [];
           for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              result[i][j] = Math.round(Math.random());
           }
       }
       console.log(result);
       this.state = {
         generations: 0,
         rows: 30,
         cols: 30,
         isGoing: false,
         speed: 500,
         gameField: result
       };
     }

     render() {
        return (
        <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state)}>Click me</button>
        )
     }

 }

 ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.body)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But i thought I supposed to initialize state inside the constructor function

Comment: You are right, that's what's recommended in the react official documentation. I just added another option.